# SQL Server 2005 Convert VARCHAR to INT but default on invalid type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a varchar(100) column in a table that contains a mix of integers (as strings) and non-integer strings. E.g.

```
| dimension varchar(100) |
| '5'                    |
| '17'                   |
| '3'                    |
| 'Pyramids'             |
| 'Western Bypass'       |
| '15'                   |
```

How can I write an expression to, e.g. sum up all the values that are valid integers? If I were to try:

```
-- should return 5 + 17 + 3 + 15 = 40
SELECT
    SUM( CONVERT( INT, dimension ) )
FROM
    mytable
```

I would receive a `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Pyramids' to data type int.` error.

Is there a test I can use in my expression, much like the `ISNULL()` function, that permits me to specify a default value if the field is not a number?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE ISNUMERIC(dimension) 
           WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT( INT, dimension ) 
           ELSE 0  
        END)
FROM
    mytable
```

The CASE should check whether `dimension` is numeric - if so, return that value. If it's not numeric, return a default value (here: 0)

Is you need to query that quite frequently, you could also add a persisted, computed column to your table which encapsulates this computation and stores the value. This way, when summing and so on, you're not always re-computing the value:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ADD NumericValue AS CASE ISNUMERIC(dimension) 
      WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT( INT, dimension ) ELSE 0 END PERSISTED
```

Now, you can `SELECT dimension, numericvalue FROM mytable` and get both values without any computation having to be executed.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! `ISNUMERIC('-1.44')` and `ISNUMERIC('12')` return 1 whereas `ISNUMERIC('foobar')` return 0. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to run into overflow problems if you have a `varchar` like `88888888888888888888888`

```
select
SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN ISNUMERIC(CheckCol+ '.0e0') = 1  AND 
      convert(decimal(38,0), CheckCol) 
      BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647 
    THEN  1
    ELSE 0
    END
)  
from Table
```