# Error converting nvarchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT 
    New_accountid AS AccountId
FROM 
    BingMapsPlatform_MSCRM.dbo.FilteredAccount WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    new_islicensed = 1
    AND new_accountid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(INT,New_AccountId)
                              FROM BingMapsPlatform_MSCRM.dbo.New_keydenylistExtensionBase WITH (NOLOCK)
                              WHERE New_AccountId IS NOT NULL)
```

I am  getting this error from this script. Please help me .

> *ErrorMessage : State 1, Line 1
>
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'account 1' to data type int.*

Comment: change to WHERE new_islicensed = '1'. Better would be to update your data type to be bit tho

Comment: i tried this but i am still getting the same errror. Any other workaround

Comment: looks like you have a value for the column that cannot be converted and that value is 'account 1'.. please check that all your values in the column can be converted to integers.

Comment: [Take a look at Aaron Bertrand's answer to similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15362692/1231866).

Comment: What data in dbo.FilteredAccount and dbo.New_keydenylistExtensionBase tables column New_AccountId?Could you give me an example of that, please?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Id an int?, could be a guid or sequential guid. If not then divide the table in half, and re run, etc until you determin the row which generates the error (i'd try with just one row to check for sillys first). Oh and copy the table contents to a backup first (but you knew that)

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing the error:

```
CONVERT(INT,New_AccountId)
```

Make a usual select on the table using the filter: `where accountId = 'account 1'`, change this value and try again.

Consider using the [ISNUMERIC(input)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933213%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) function to determine if its nummeric before converting and if its not then use 0 or -1 as a default value (Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419469/395659) for an example).